# Code block rendered incorrectly at question but correct in edit window

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, code-formatting, markdown-rendering

I came upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40091530/3959259). On a first look I thought that the code was formatted with a backtick starting and ending every line:

> [image]

I decided to correct this but when I clicked on edit I saw that it was correctly formatted with three backticks before and three backticks after the code. It was even rendered correctly in the edit window:

> [image]

Is this a rendering bug or did I miss something in the markup?

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SE: [Display issue of three-backticks formatted code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330102/289905).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The question was last edited before backtick formatting was introduced (asked on Oct 17 '16) and the layout has been cached. The rendered output only gets updated when some modifications happen to the question.

I have now edited the question and the rendering has been updated.

Comment: Are triple-backtick code blocks kosher? Or no?

Comment: @Michael Yes, now they are. But in 2016 they weren't.

Comment: Support for GitHub-style triple-backtick code-block demarcators was silently introduced around the beginning of this year (2019). Prior to that, there was no support for them at all, so the backticks on that post just got interpreted as requesting inline code formatting. @Michael

Comment: @CodyGray It wasn't exactly silent https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322000/253521

Comment: FWIW the generally agreed upon term is [fenced code blocks](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks#fenced-code-blocks)

Comment: Just happened to me. F5 solved it.