# Possible Markdown Code Fences Rendering Bug

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40625259) (now fixed, see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fkd0d.png)) code fences ```` ``` ```` are rendered like `inline code`. However, [editing preview](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40625259/edit/7d945194-b4c7-4ffd-844b-808e39d17e38) renders it correctly.

Source:

````markdown
Killing all other node processes worked for me
ie.
```
ps -ef | grep node 
```
to find those process and 
...
````

Occurs in Firefox and Chromium on Ubuntu.

Comment: There needs to be blank line in front of a code fence to compensate for the slightly off differences between the client and server side common mark parser

Comment: Is it important enough to be mentioned in the [Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)?

Comment: I would rather have the parser fixed.

Comment: @rene - in 6-8 weeks perhaps? Given how unkeen SE seems to be of late to make *substantial* changes to the public platform, it might not be a bad idea to ask for the formatting help wording to be amended

Comment: Possibly related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385524, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330102

Comment: @OlegValter IIRC both the client and server render are open-source projects from other maintainers. I'm not sure if this is a problem caused by the SE implementation or an upstream bug. In the latter case we can only hope someone has the bug reported there and have it fixed for a major release. It becomes a bit like the situation we had with Google Prettify ...

Comment: @rene - do you know which one this is? I can take a look, but to my shame, I am not entirely familiar with the software that powers StackExchange itself frontend-wise (apart from knowing that there is a Stacks project that encompasses the frontend components)

Comment: @OlegValter from: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark "For the curious: this means we’re replacing PageDown with markdown-it on the client side and MarkdownSharp with markdig on the server side."

Comment: @Luuklag ah, this one slipped my mind, was even bookmarked, thanks!

Comment: @Yatin Already mentioned by Bill Tür. Is there any way to fix this bug without microscopic edits of each affected post?

Comment: @nik7 nope, I am not aware of any other way. I am >2k so my edits apply immediately. so if the post has nothing to correct then I just add and remove some random text and leave an explanation in the edit history (like a link to a meta post).